# Pop element after array after less than condition mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

So, I have this mongoDB document structure

```js
{
  "_id": 111111111,
  "uname": "john_doe",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": "dfdefwdfwef",
      "maxAge": 1627714371218,
      "details": "Details"
    },
    {
      "id": "papapsdasdp",
      "maxAge": 1627661637378,
      "details": "Details 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

where the maxAge is a Date.now() integer representing a time in the future. Now, I want to fetch the data from the DB (which I have successfully done) and pop the JSON object where the Date.now() i.e current time is greater than maxAge (indicating that the task has expired). The way I am trying to do it is.

```js
let user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { uname: "john_doe" },
    {
      $pop: {
        tasks: {
          maxAge: {
            $lt: Date.now(),
          },
        },
      },
    }
```

But doing it this way causes an error. Please help me out with this... Thanks in advance, :-)

Comment: use `$pull` operator to remove document from array.

Comment: What is the error?